# pass arguments to scrapy rules from command line or dynamically modify rules

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python programming and I am having a hard time getting python crawling script work. I need tips from you to fix it.

Actually, I have a working scrapy script that crawls through a given url and extracts the links. I want it to make it work on any dynamically given url. so I started passing the start urls and domains to scrapy through the command line like below.

```
scrapy crawl myCrawler -o test.json -t json -a allowedDomains="xxx" -a startUrls="xxx" -a allowedPaths="xxx"
```

However, it does not work. looks like the Rules is not getting the values from arguments. Due to my lack of python skills, I not able to figure how to get this fixed. Some one please help me here.

Here is the code snippet.

```
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):

  name = "myCrawler"

   def __init__(self, allowedDomains='', startUrls='',allowedPaths='', *args, **kwargs):
       super(DmozSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.allowedDomains = allowedDomains
       self.startUrls = startUrls
       self.allowedPaths = allowedPaths
       self.allowed_domains = [allowedDomains]
       self.start_urls = [startUrls]

   rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(allowedPaths), allow_domains=allowedDomains), callback="parse_items",
                     follow=True),)
```

Comment: You've posted a bunch of code which does not include the actual command line parsing.  So we can't help you.

Comment: oops missed highlight that piece of code, highlighted now.

Comment: Are there any errors? What is content of test.json?

Comment: There are no errors, the scraping is successful but with zero items. test.json is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily got it working, found answer at [How to dynamically set Scrapy rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509489/how-to-dynamically-set-scrapy-rules)

Here is the working code

```
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):

  name = "myCrawler"

   def __init__(self, allowedDomains='', startUrls='',allowedPaths='', *args, **kwargs):
       super(DmozSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.allowedDomains = allowedDomains
       self.startUrls = startUrls
       self.allowedPaths = allowedPaths
       self.allowed_domains = [allowedDomains]
       self.start_urls = [startUrls]
       DmozSpider.rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(allowedPaths), allow_domains=allowedDomains), callback="parse_items",
                     follow=True),)
       super(DmozSpider, self)._compile_rules()
```