# How to override sitemap_rules in scrapy Sitemap spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to dynamically add `sitemap_rules` in the spider using the `init` method. I'm able to change the `sitemap_urls` using the same method but `sitemap_rules` doesn't get overriden. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from myspider.items import MyItem
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(SitemapSpider):
    sitemap_urls = []
    sitemap_rules = []
    name = "testspider"

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.sitemap_rules = [('*.Attraction_Review.*', 'parse_data'),]
        start_url = "http://tripadvisor-sitemaps.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/att/en_IN/sitemap_en_IN_attraction_review_index.xml"
        self.sitemap_urls = [start_url]
        #dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        ......
        yield item
```

In the above code `parse_data` is never called. It works fine if I mention the same rules in the `sitemap_rules` variable in the beginning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically set Scrapy rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509489/how-to-dynamically-set-scrapy-rules)

Comment: No. But I did solved it using scrapy sitemap code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using [this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py) code. Here's the code change:

```
def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
    super(RecipeSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
    rules = [('https://www.tripadvisor.in/Attraction_Review.*', 'parse_data'),]
    self._cbs = []
    for r, c in rules:
        if isinstance(c, six.string_types):
            c = getattr(self, c)
        self._cbs.append((regex(r), c))
```